# Off-topic issues that should be migrated

Tags: discussion, migration, scope

Being a regular contributor to answers in the [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) tag, I find that there are a lot of questions submitted that are clearly "off-topic" by the scope defined for Stack Overflow in that they are specifically "not generally about programming" and are actually related to administration topics.

Specifically I mean:

- The question does not relate to the setup of a development environment for the purposes of development or development testing.
- The question involves the use for tools for data import or export not specifically related to a programming question or involving a programming solution.
- The question specifically denotes terms used in administration of database environments in the context. Therefore generally speaks of "sharding" and "replication" concepts that are not related to the programming interface.

So my main point for consideration is "Point 1" as given, in that I need to consider whether this reasonably looks like someones development effort or not. But my problem seems to be, that there are many questions that are asked that do not meet these criteria and are still being submitted and "remain" on Stack Overflow despite their beign "off-topic".

The problem I see is that, despite the general objective being to define different sites for "specific topics", various contributors prefer to submit their commentary and answers on Stack Overflow as a "site" for the sole reason that it is likely to benefit their own "score" as it were, and the motivation to "move" the questions to an appropriate site ( as I thought the intention of spawning these sites was for ) is removed by that personal reward.

I really do not know what the answer is, even if there possibly is one. But I cannot see the point of establishing sites such as [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) unless they actually get used for their purpose, and these "off-topic" questions and answers are actually removed from a site like Stack Overflow.

So am I insane for asking this? Is it completely illogical and out of step with the community or the intended usage of the sites?

I don't know, I'm really just a newb and have not been hanging around for years. But it seems wrong to me anyway. So if there are specific forums, then what can be done to discourage the responses? Or more specifically, how to encourage the **right** responses of moving the questions to the correct forum?

I am prepared to monitor and answer relevant questions proposed on another site. Should others not be prepared to do so?

**EDIT:** The understanding here is that I believe communities such as [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) and [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) were created for a reason. If questions are actually focused on those areas then that is where they should be addressed. Those communities should be embraced and not discarded just because people wish to bolster their SO reputation score. Unfortunately I see the latter as the case.

Comment: In regards to "tools for data import and export". If these are things that a programmer would need to do as part of their day-to-day work (and many of us do), I would say this falls in the on-topic as these are tools commonly used during software development.

Comment: @Oded I completely agree. But sharding and replication and oplog monitoring are not. Far too many questions in this tag with those subjects have my close ( migration vote ) only. Is there really some reason why those topics belong on SO and are not migrated to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) as an example?  This is the real reason I am asking this question

Comment: @NeilLunn If you find questions that are "off-topic" for SO or would be better suited for DBA.SE, then vote to close them.  DBA is one of the options to move questions to. It is entirely possible that users in the mongodb tag are not aware that there is [similar tag](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) on DBA.  Another thing you could do would stop in to chat over on DBA and ask users if they will help migrate a mongodb question.

Comment: Lets start with this - do you agree that our sites are not so narrowly scoped that some questions can, in fact, be considered to be on-topic on more than one?

Comment: @Oded Whoa there. This is not a complaint. I'm merely asking for advice or an opinion. I could say the same to `@bluefeet` but tagging does not work that way. So does someone have something productive to say? Close votes do not work when the community seems more interested in raising their SO score. Flagging seems not to be the answer. The only thing I can see as an answer is general moderator support for keeping separated communities. Which for some reason I thought would reach those people here. Can anyone here discern criticism from constructive commentary? I hoped they could.

Comment: @bluefeet I think you really missed the point, I added more information in other comments but specifically with the last edit I just added to the question. There really are off-topic questions regularly added in this tag. I am all about building the community for where they actually should be asked. So constructive answers are very welcome with respect to the question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't think I missed your point, it is possible for questions to be on-topic on more than one site, SO/DBA are examples as is SO/CodeReview. It is likely that users of some tags don't realize that their questions _might_ be a better fit on other sites or they _might_ get better answers on other sites. All I'm saying is that if you believe a question is more on-topic for another site then you can vote to migrate it and if you are the single vote to migrate, leave a comment explaining why it should migrate or go to chat asking for additional votes.

Comment: Reading the post again (it is really difficult to see what you are trying to get at), do you truly see other sites on the network as simply migration targets and not communities in their own right?

Comment: recommended reading: [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/165773). History has shown that migration from SO is not always healthy for target sites. See also: [Suggested migrations review at target site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151345/165773) and questions linked to it

Answer (score 8):

You can't force the community to follow your rules.

The Stack Overflow community is huge. It is not homogeneous and different people have different opinions about these issues.

What each and every one of us can do is best effort according to their understanding.

That means - if you see something that is off topic, you downvote, flag for migration (if appropriate - we don't migrate bad questions) and if you wish, go to chat and rally the troop to help with closure/migration.

And then, move on.

Comment: Congratulations on saying something constructive. Not. I bow to the awsomeness of people who cannot even read and spell my name correctly even when it is put in front on them. Very constructive answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn - guess you never make typos. Ever. Ad hominem attacks are not really constructive either, you know? If you want to say something about what I wrote, don't attack something completely unrelated that I or someone else did.

Comment: Will you please understand that your "answer" is not constructive to the point. I close vote, 1 vote only. When I saw that then I down-vote. Getting a little tired of my down-votes outranking up-votes. Does it make a difference? No. Am I trying to do something constructive for the community here? Yes. The funny thing is "don't attack!" seriously? The last time "I was attacked" and defended y position to another diamond tagged moderator I ended up suspended for my audacity in doing so (history repeats). So constructive, is there a way this conversation might reach the community using the tag?

Comment: @Neil - you didn't seem to make a point in your post. It is unclear. Can you edit it and explain what your point is then? As for your history - I didn't bring that in - you have. I have simply asked you to not give arguments that have nothing to do with the post. **That** is not constructive. Now, will you please clarify what exactly you are trying to say?

Comment: What exactly is not clear? And therefore what this fails to answer. **1**. Why have other sites if it is okay to ask non-programming topic questions on SO? **2.** Some **help please** if the general attendees in the community do not follow this model. **3.** Flagging and even commenting here seems pointless unless someone gets up and does something. The general response says no-one will. Sit with the status Quo? Go back to point one. I just want to see someone get up and do something rather than procrastinate.

Comment: 1. It is not OK, but the existence of other sites has no bearing on that. 2. What help do you seek? What exactly do you feel can be done? 3. People are doing. Just not what **you** want. Seems like a disconnect there, eh, @Neil?

Comment: Why bother when you just do not listen or read. How many times do I have to say it. Close votes (or migration) do not work when the "community" is only interested in how mush SO rep points they can gain by answering "off-topic" questions. Why bother having other sites dedicated to this otherwise? That is pretty simple and clearly stated in the question. What is the solution? Nothing here in this stream of comments (and I hate that also). I'm not a moderator, you and other wise commentators here apparently are. What are you going to do about it? Aside from nothing that is.

Comment: How do you know what people's motives are? I'm having a lot of my answers migrated and I don't want to start hanging out on another site for various reasons plus I follow multiple tags on SO.  I really don't care about my rep, I just don't want to constantly have things sent to a site I don't want to be on and then have to respond to responses to my old answers.  I really would not assume you know the secret motives of everyone.