# Why all the Stack Exchange sites when everyone just asks on Stack Overflow anyway?

Tags: discussion, tags, statistics, area-51

To me this just doesn't make sense or really in the inverse it does make sense but it just doesn't seem to be adhered to in any way.

The objective here seems to be to spawn off another Stack Exchange site in order to keep the "domain" topics "on-topic" for a particular subject. I think this is right but there is a clear problem here.

People still keep asking the "off-domain" questions on Stack Overflow. And Okay, that is inevitable and I would not expect that to stop. There are migration options and there are close options and that should be fine right? After all there is the fair option to use them.

But in reality they basically never get used. At least I see heavy usage cases where they never get used and mostly by the legacy people who hang around expecting to answer "non-programming related questions".

One of those things where I don't see easy answers because you cannot "police state" people into doing something ( or at least it's not a really palatable idea ). But at the same time it seems to operate to the antithesis of the goal.

Should there really be these separate domains? It seems to make sense. But if even the higher reputation users here refuse to use them in favor of staying on their Stack Overflow account and that goes without question, then that seems counterproductive.

It would be nice to see a productive approach or strategy to working towards the separate domain logic. Or in lieu of that, a reasonable argument to just keep it all in the same place.

Trying to make sense of it all.

Comment: I see I placed yet another "Why Bother reading the question and just respond with downvotes because I think that's cool" topics. Complete lack of useful input.

Comment: So you would have cooking, DIY, gardening, English usage, etc. etc. questions all asked on Stack Overflow? I don't know about you but *that* would make me hand in my diamond and quit the site.

Comment: I haven't downvoted (yet, at least), and I have read the question. Now I have a question myself: What are you talking about? Examples?

Comment: I wouldn't say everyone asks on SO, the other sites get plenty of questions, etc otherwise they wouldn't survive.

Comment: @ChrisF You didn't read the question. I'm saying the opposite. I **don't** want that. But this is what everyone else I see is allowing.

Comment: @NeilLunn - ah. In that case can you point to any examples that haven't been closed in short order?

Comment: Please just [edit] the question to include links to a few example posts that you feel illustrate your point.

Comment: So many generalisations, so little actual proof.

Comment: @ChrisF That would be a blog post in a half if you really wanted it. My personal example is the mongodb tag, but I am sure the sql tags are equally rife with clear DBA type questions that never get migrated/closed/whatever despite enough people of enough reputation score to do so visting on a regular basis. Most are the abusers themselves. IMHO, but the inverse is the argument from people that this is not abuse and is just fine. Which is it? Other sites or one site? Haven't looked. Am I at -20 yet. And you wonder why people don't ask?

Comment: Most questions that aren't on-topic for SO, by a humongous margin, are posted on other sites in the SE network. Heck, you posted this question on Meta instead of SO... Sure, some slip through, but usually they get handled fast enough. Some questions that are on-topic on other SE sites are also on topic on SO, but that's no reason to just get rid of those other sites.

Comment: @NeilLunn As far as the DBA/SO connection there is crossover between those sites just like SO has with Code Review. That doesn't mean that we should dissolve the other sites and merge them with SO.  Both DBA and Code Review have very specific standards for what is and is not on-topic.

Comment: Delete closed questions faster than 60 days, then compare how those enabling these questions by answering and sitting pretty on +3 upvotes react

Comment: @MartijnPieters Tell you what. Suggest a perfectly valid topic along these lines you think is productive and I'll take it with a grain of salt. If you read through this it happens all of the time and I think people generally do experience it. Maybe I should have flamed certain tags and question links. Would that be better?

Comment: @NeilLunn: Yet I disagree that it happens all the time. So it is your word against mine now, and until you come up with some concrete examples, there is no point in having a discussion at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not arguing. Just asking for advice. Do you want a question with concrete examples or not? Because there is nothing productive being said here. Maybe other tags play more "nice" or "cooperatively", but it's not what I am seeing.

Comment: @NeilLunn: that's what everyone is asking you to do, add concrete examples that illustrate what you are talking about.

Comment: @Neil You posted a rant with no examples (even if that's not what you meant). What do you expect?

Comment: Isn't this just a rant-styled continuation of [Off-topic issues that should be migrated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254661) ?

Comment: @Seth people with a respectable level of intelligence to ask reasonable questions and not behave like ... well you can read the rest yourself. Makes me laugh the "be nice" when I see reaction like this. Take a look back on the up-voted comments that were completely unqualified or considering the response in thread. Ask better? Sure. Treat Better? Glad the example has been made. Not solely your fault.

Comment: @NeilLunn As a moderator on the DBA site I can tell you we do get a decent number of migrations. Does every qualified Q get migrated to DBA? Nope. Does every garbage question on SO get closed? Not by a long shot. But we don't reject them if they get sent over. There is a bit of overlap between the sites for sure. However, there is a benefit to having a Q looked at by a smaller group of domain experts, especially w/r/t signal to noise ratio.

Comment: So, instead of providing some examples to illustrate what you're saying in the question (rant), you just tell "us" we lack a certain measure of intelligence. Way to go.

Comment: So Instead of asking a good question you decide to insult my intelligence? Your choice. I was giving you the benefit of the doubt until now.

Comment: What are you talking about?, you posted **your** generalization of an issue that many here haven't experienced with no proof whatsoever other than "I've seen it and it happens **all** the time!". People have been asking you to edit your question so it's less a rant and more an objective issue.

Answer (score 18):

Speaking as a moderator on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) and a heavy lurker on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), I can tell you that a lot of questions are *considered* for migration, but many simply don't make the cut. I can't speak for other non-trilogy sites, but we do try to maintain high bars for both quality and complexity. So some questions won't get migrated because they're basic SQL programming questions or they're just not good enough. We also try to prevent questions like "can't ping my server" and questions we can't authoritatively answer with any confidence, such as licensing questions.

Many people find Stack Overflow simply due to critical mass. I often spot questions there that would be a perfect fit for our site, but that doesn't necessarily make them off-topic on SO. In a lot of cases that I have seen, when it's been suggested the question be moved to dba.SE, the response has been that they had never heard of it. These are usually newer users, and often the question quality isn't quite there, but it has happened with really good questions, too.

Mostly, though, at least from my observations of questions that might try to get migrated, it's that the question isn't good enough to belong anywhere else, either. A terrible question here is not going to be migrated because what good is giving someone else a terrible question to deal with? For some background on what we're trying to avoid, see:

- [Please stop using SoftwareEngineering.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

In most cases they'll just reject the migration - so it's a bunch of work moderators have to do, time they could have spent answering meta questions questioning the usefulness of having more than one site.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it's like that. There are some overlaps in on-topic fields (for instance, programming softwares and tools are on-topic on both Stack Overflow and SuperUser), but by no means that means that we accept any question asked on general computing on Stack Overflow.

Just because you haven't had the chance to use them doesn't mean they aren't being used.

If an off-topic question gets asked, close/migrate/flag it. I don't understand what the problem with that is really...

Comment: There is no problem, really...